# Preference library styling using the material components theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, preferencefragment, material-components-android

I'm using preference library(`androidx.preference:preference`) along with the material components theming(`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`). I'm looking for a proper way for styling(font, size, color) the category text(without changing the whole layout) as well as the preference text itself. 
The [official preferences library sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-preferences) shows a way to show a styled preference using HTML tags inside the string resource, but Im looking for a way to change it(and titles) via theming:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?